# Spring Boot + JPA inject EntityManager no EntityManager available

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, entitymanager

I am trying to annotation-inject an EntityManager into my DAO using spring boot but am getting an `InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException` saying there is no transactional EntityManager available. I am under the impression that Spring Boot will basically take care of everything for me as long as it has my DataSource info from `application.yml` and I tag the `EntityManager` field in my DAO with `@PersitenceContext`, so that I don't need an EntityManagerFactory in my own code nor a `persistence.xml` file. Am I wrong about that?

My DAO:

```
@Repository
public class PersonDaoJpa implements PersonDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    ...

    DAO methods

    ...
}
```

My Spring Boot configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {ProgramInfo.BASE_PACKAGE})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {ProgramInfo.BASE_PACKAGE})
public class PersonServiceConfiguration {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(PersonServiceConfiguration.class, args);
    }
}
```

My JUnit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = PersonServiceConfiguration.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
    TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
    DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@DatabaseSetup("/test_data_start.xml")
public class PersonDaoJpaTest {

    @Autowired
    private PersonDaoJpa dao;

    ...

    JUnit tests 

    ...
}
```

My `application.yml` file:

```
spring:
    profiles.active: default

---

spring:
    profiles: default

spring.datasource:
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database?autoReconnect=true
    username: user
    password: pwd

spring.jpa.show-sql: false
spring.jpa.database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

And finally my `pom.xml` file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>  
  <groupId>myId</groupId>
  <artifactId>myArtifictId</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.springtestdbunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test-dbunit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <repositories>
      <repository>
          <id>spring-releases</id>
          <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
      </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
      <pluginRepository>
          <id>spring-releases</id>
          <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
      </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Here is the full exception I get:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No transactional EntityManager available; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No transactional EntityManager available
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:410)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:216)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417)
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
at com.accenture.javadojo.orgchart.dao.PersonDaoJpa$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6c935a0d.flush(<generated>)
at dao.PersonDaoJpaTest.testUpdateInvalid(PersonDaoJpaTest.java:92)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:224)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No transactional EntityManager available
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:275)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy54.flush(Unknown Source)
at com.accenture.javadojo.orgchart.dao.PersonDaoJpa.flush(PersonDaoJpa.java:63)
at com.accenture.javadojo.orgchart.dao.PersonDaoJpa$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ed9d6faf.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
... 33 more
```

**UPDATE:**
The following JUnit test passes when I comment out `dao.flush()`:

```
@Test
public void testFind() {

    Person one = dao.find(1l);
    //dao.flush();
    assertNotNull("User was not found", one);
    assertEquals("Last name not as expected", "one", one.getLastName());
    assertEquals("First name not as expected", "start1", one.getFirstName());
}
```

but with it uncommented, I get the same exception as described above. The `find` and `flush` methods are as follows:

```
@Override
public Person find(Long id) {

    return em.find(Person.class, id);
}

public void flush() {

    em.flush();
}
```

Comment: try putting @Transactional on your repository?

Comment: If you are able to upload a full project as an example to github, I wouldn't mind perusing the code to see if I could get it working with as little custom configuration as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There more specific you become in your implementations, the more Spring Boot will back off in what it does for you.

Because you have created your own implementations, instead of defining an interface which implements CrudRepository (for example), you will now also need to configure your own entity manager.

Here's some documentation links that can show you how to do what you need:

```
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.create-instances.java-config
```